# Effect of natural environment on the development of cultures

Tags: world-building

Let there be this quantitative question: **how do the specifics of a natural environment influence the development of a newborn culture?**

*Please note: I'm not looking for any deus ex machinas, divine planes and answers incorporating high magic. Let this be a question set in a realistic world governed by the rules of physics.*

Following are the specifics of the question:

- Which environmental factors are to be considered relevant here? Is it
  the *climate, temperature zone, humidity, weather characteristics,
  fertility of land, local ecosystems and animals, availability of
  resources, natural dangers and diseases*, etc.? Where in the cultural mosaic do these specific factors manifest themselves (one by one)?
- Can the natural environment be a decisive factor in the development
  of a culture? Take the (un)availability of basic resources (foods)
  for example: can this be a determining factor in developing into,
  say, a liberal or restrictive/hostile society? Etc. What other
  decisive factors could be considered here (if any) - and to which
  societal characteristics should they lead?
- To flesh out the explanation in all angles, do you have any
  qualitative examples that may be shown here? (as in significant environmental
  factors on cultures *in the classical mediterranean, in the viking
  society*, etc. ...)
- A bonus question (to be able to apply all that theory onto
  something): what could an underground society (lots of rocks and
  caves) develop into, culture-wise? (assuming that some limited
  amounts of sunlight and food sources are available). Note: *if this sub-question seems too vague (as in lacking some required data), feel free to use your imagination (to add that lacking data to the big picture by yourself).*

Comment: How is this question best answered by an RPG expert instead of an anthropologist or the history stack exchange? (This *is* an excellent PhD dissertation though...)

Comment: This is a fascinating (if dauntingly broad) question, but without narrative construct or context (even sandbox games are a kind of narrative) it's not answerable as an RPG question. Maybe break it down into a progressively posted set of smaller-topic questions relating these ideas to your gameplay experience goals and how a culture/environment can be designed to help achieve them?

Comment: Take a look at the citation web around: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1468-2451.1997.tb00039.x/abstract this book citing a 1896 (yes, that's the right century) [essay](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=fW7JfT8ovaMC&lpg=PA1&ots=Eub8vH_5mi&dq=influence%20of%20environment%20culture%20anthropology&lr&pg=PR12#v=onepage&q=environment&f=false) about this topic and so on and so forth.

Comment: [See Also](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=yUUYN3X18dwC&lpg=PR7&ots=88EtBOpIW2&dq=influence%20of%20environment%20culture%20anthropology&lr&pg=PR7#v=onepage&q=influence%20of%20environment%20culture%20anthropology&f=false) and the 2377 citations of it.

Comment: Crossposted: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8431/effect-of-natural-environment-on-the-development-of-cultures